# vue js display selected img using v-bind:src

Tags: vue.js

I have a an object is being displayed in a select menu. I am simply trying to bind the selected image to the screen. Not sure what I should display inside of the :src="". Can someone please let me know what needs to be added

```html
<select>
  <optgroup v-for="[folder, files] in filteredList" :label="folder">
    <option v-for="img in files" :value="img.path">{{img}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>


<span>image here: </span> <img v-bind:src="img in files" width="150" height="150" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `<select>` form control with a model (as choosing any option in your current code doesn't change anything from Vue perspective):

```
<select v-model="selectedPath">
  <optgroup>...</optgroup>
</select>
```

Do not forget to define this model in `data` section of your component/app. Then you can use value of this model in `v-bind: src` expression.

```
<img v-bind:src="selectedPath" width="150" height="150" />
```

And here's a snippet illustrating all of this in action:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedPath: '',
    files: [
      { path: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/is3wI.png?s=64.jpg', title: 'Bee' },
      { path: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kONSg.jpg?s=64', title: 'Circle' },
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedPath">
    <option v-for="img in files" :label="img.title" :value="img.path">{{img}}</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <img v-bind:src="selectedPath" width="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: still doesnt display the image

Comment: Is there any network request going out when choosing a different option? Just trying to understand whether or not model is properly connected here to imgsrc. Can you add some text output to span to check that path itself is assigned correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, sometimes vue doesn't update the image when the `src` change, try add a `key` to the `img` element

```
// Quick fix
<img :key="selectedPath" :src="imgSourceValue" ... />
```